# Rolling counts with TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Let me preface this with I'm not exactly sure how to ask this question in the first place which has been a big hinderance in trying to find an answer. As a result, I might be using completely wrong terminology.

I want to get counts of distinct users over a period of time using a window.

My data table has these columns: Id, User, RequestedOn, Query where requests are captured over time by the system. For example, over the course of eight hours, the system is queried 370 different times by 78 different users.

I figured out how to do this through brute force and ignore (BF&I), but like many BF&I approaches, it doesn't scale worth beans.

In these examples, the window size for counting is 8 hours; the number of distinct users for a given 8 hour time slot.

```
Select '5/28/17 15:00' [StartingFrom], Count(Distinct [UserName]) [Users] From [vwRequests] Where [RequestedOn] >= '5/28/17 15:00' And [RequestedOn] <= '5/28/17 23:00' Union
Select '5/28/17 14:00' [StartingFrom], Count(Distinct [UserName]) [Users] From [vwRequests] Where [RequestedOn] >= '5/28/17 14:00' And [RequestedOn] <= '5/28/17 22:00' Union
Select '5/28/17 13:00' [StartingFrom], Count(Distinct [UserName]) [Users] From [vwRequests] Where [RequestedOn] >= '5/28/17 13:00' And [RequestedOn] <= '5/28/17 21:00' Union
Select '5/28/17 12:00' [StartingFrom], Count(Distinct [UserName]) [Users] From [vwRequests] Where [RequestedOn] >= '5/28/17 12:00' And [RequestedOn] <= '5/28/17 20:00' Union
Select '5/28/17 11:00' [StartingFrom], Count(Distinct [UserName]) [Users] From [vwRequests] Where [RequestedOn] >= '5/28/17 11:00' And [RequestedOn] <= '5/28/17 19:00' Union
Select '5/28/17 10:00' [StartingFrom], Count(Distinct [UserName]) [Users] From [vwRequests] Where [RequestedOn] >= '5/28/17 10:00' And [RequestedOn] <= '5/28/17 18:00' Union
Select '5/28/17 09:00' [StartingFrom], Count(Distinct [UserName]) [Users] From [vwRequests] Where [RequestedOn] >= '5/28/17 09:00' And [RequestedOn] <= '5/28/17 17:00' Union
Select '5/28/17 08:00' [StartingFrom], Count(Distinct [UserName]) [Users] From [vwRequests] Where [RequestedOn] >= '5/28/17 08:00' And [RequestedOn] <= '5/28/17 16:00'
```

I figure there has got to be a better way of doing this but I don't know where to even start looking.

Pointers would be fantastic!

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you need a `recursive cte` like this

```
DECLARE @StartTime datetime = '2017-05-28 00:00:00'
DECLARE @EndTime datetime = '2017-05-29 00:00:00'

;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT @StartTime AS StartPeriod, dateadd(hour,8,@StartTime) AS EndPeriod
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT dateadd(hour,1,StartPeriod), dateadd(hour,1,EndPeriod) AS EndPeriod
    FROM cte
    WHERE cte.StartPeriod < @EndTime
)
-- cte returns
--StartPeriod                EndPeriod
--2017-05-28 00:00:00.000   2017-05-28 08:00:00.000
--2017-05-28 01:00:00.000   2017-05-28 09:00:00.000
--2017-05-28 02:00:00.000   2017-05-28 10:00:00.000
--2017-05-28 03:00:00.000   2017-05-28 11:00:00.000
--2017-05-28 04:00:00.000   2017-05-28 12:00:00.000
--2017-05-28 05:00:00.000   2017-05-28 13:00:00.000
--.................
SELECT c.StartPeriod, c.EndPeriod, Users FROM cte c
OUTER APPLY (
             SELECT Count(Distinct [UserName]) AS Users -- i think you should use Count(distinct UserId) instead of UserName
             From [vwRequests] Where [RequestedOn] BETWEEN c.StartPeriod AND c.EndPeriod
          ) ca
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: This is magical and does everything I need. It also introduces me to the concept of Common Table Expressions which I did not know a thing about and have more reading to do. Thank you so much! (And yes, counting UserId will likely be faster in the long run.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to optimize the performace of the existing query without changing it too much, replace `UNION` with `UNION ALL` and add an some indexes on the Username and RequestedOn columns.

If `vwRequests` is a table (not a view), try these to see what works best for you:

```
CREATE INDEX IX1 ON dbo.vwRequests (RequestedOn, Username)
CREATE INDEX IX2 ON dbo.vwRequests (Username, RequestedOn)
```

If `vwRequests` is a view, you can try adding indexes on the base table or changing the view to be an indexed view.

If you want to rewrite your query, you can start by doing something like this:

```
SELECT x1.StartingFrom, x2.Users
FROM (VALUES (8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15)) h (h)
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT DATEADD(HOUR,h,'20170528') AS [StartingFrom]
) x1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT vr.Username) AS Users
    FROM dbo.vwRequests vr
    WHERE vr.RequestedOn BETWEEN x1.StartingFrom AND DATEADD(HOUR,8,x1.StartingFrom)
) x2
```

Comment: Thank you! This is not quite what I need; it works though it doesn't look like it easily scales. However, this gave me new things to go look up, learn, and trails to go dive into. For that I am grateful and hence the upvote. <3